# How can i find out which character gets deleted in a tinymce editor on backspace (before it actually gets deleted)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, tinymce

Assuming the cursor position in a tinymce editor is inside a paragraph.
When a user hits backspace i need to know which character will get deleted.
It is necessary to know this before the character gets removed (onKeyDown is ok, onKeyUp is too late).

**How can i find out which character gets deleted on backspace (before it actually gets deleted)?**

Comment: I wonder why do you want to do this? May be there is a better solution to this problem.

Comment: we have non-visible soft hyphen in the editor text, when a user pushes backspace i need to find out if one of those soft hyphen will get removed in order to find out if it is necessary to delete one additional character else the user won't see that pushing backspace will remove anything (even if it does, but the soft-hyphen to be removed is not visible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in one of my plugins i set onKeyDown

```
ed.onKeyDown.add(function(ed, evt) {
  if (paragraph && evt.keyCode == 8 && ed.selection.isCollapsed()) {

        //insert special marker char
    var value = '<span id="__ircaret" class="ircaret">\u2060</span>';
    ed.selection.setContent(value, {format : 'raw', no_events: 1});

    // node is the dom node the caret is placed in
    var node = ed.selection.getNode();
    var node_content = $(node).text();

    var position = node_content.search('\u2060');

        // this is the character
    var char_vor_cursor = position != 0 ? node_content.slice(position - 1, position) : '';

    // Test for soft-hyphen
    if (char_vor_cursor != '' && char_vor_cursor.charCodeAt(0) == 173) {
        // correct innerHTML
                var text_after_backspace = node_content.slice(0, position - 1) + '<span id="__ircaret" class="ircaret">\u2060</span>' +  node_content.slice(position + 1);
        node.innerHTML = text_after_backspace;
    }
    var caret_node = $(node).find('#__ircaret').get(0);

    // select caretnode and remove
    ed.selection.select(caret_node);
    $(ed.getBody()).find('.ircaret').remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the var `node`?

Comment: @JoelWorsham: sorry. node = ed.selection.getNode();

Comment: I can get the position and character but not able to delete them. why?

Comment: got it: char_vor_cursor.charCodeAt(0) == 173  :)

Answer (score 3):

The code above doesn't take into account backspacing in the middle of a paragraph, or backspacing a whole selection.  Try something like [the a-tools plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/a-tools) (although there are several others like it) in combination with the following event handler:

```
jQuery('input, textarea').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 8) {
    var selection = jQuery(this).getSelection();
    var selStart  = (selection.length) ? selection.start : selection.start - 1;
    var selEnd    = selection.end;
    alert(jQuery(this).val().slice(selStart, selEnd));
  }
});
```

Comment: i do not have an input element or a textarea but a content-editable iframe, but i will try if this code is applicable

Comment: this is not defined when i use "$( ed.getDoc() ).keydown(function(e) {..." (ed.getDoc returns iframes document)

Comment: I don't have time to write some code now, but have you tried looking into the `tinyMCE.get('foo').selection` property?  `foo` is the name of your editor.

Comment: yes, i am familiar with the tinymce selection. problem here is that i am not able to assign an event handler to each paragraph i create in the editor on startup